# Saving user preferences/settings for vscode extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

What are the best practices to store user settings for the extension? I can think of saving them in some specific format in the text file. Is there any integrated way of doing that using `vscode` API?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

VSCode extensions typically contribute settings to be used in [user and workspace `settings.json` files](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings).

Settings are [registered via `contributes.configuration`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-capabilities/common-capabilities#configuration) in an extension's `package.json`, and the allowed values can flexibly be described with a JSON schema (which also allows for code completion in the JSON file). The value of settings can then be checked by using the [`workspace.getConfiguration()` API](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#workspace.getConfiguration).

There is also a [sample extension](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/master/configuration-sample) that showcases the Configuration API in vscode-extension-samples.

Having a separate file just for a specific extension's settings would be a bit unusual.